# automatic system updates , how to configure APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval to clean obsoleted cache only?

Tags: apt, updates

I've been using auto update for a while, but recently I discovered the downloaded package cache missing in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, some deb packages, like Skype, are removed, and I don't know why.

So I'm thinking about this option: `APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval`, currently set to `0`.

This page didn't provide much information:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know what you are doing don't use commandline. Use GUIs like synaptic. There are a lot of options to configure how Ubuntu should treat available update. To start it just press Alt+F2 and when dialog appears type command

```
gksudo synaptic
```

fill in password and when synaptic opens go to 
settings->repository 
see the updates tab and select options as per your flavor

Comment: right , i shouldn't really waste time here , i see an auto-update entry inside

Answer (score -1):

The command just cleans up the local cache.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html